# Equal or greater than with whereIn or array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array:

```
array:3 [▼
    0 => "5"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "20"
]
```

This is values of discounts I need to brings the products that has Equal or greater than the value in array:

```
Product::whereHas('discounts',function($q) use($value){
        $q->where('type','percentage')->whereIn('value','>=',$value);
 });
```

`$value` is the above array

So, I need to bring the products that has discount 5% or more | and also bring the products that has 10% or more | same thing with 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the min and get all discounts greater then that:

```php
Product::whereHas('discounts',function($q) use($value){
    $q->where('type','percentage')
      ->where('value','>=',min($value));
});
```

Comment: I tried that before but got this error:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: it should be `->where('value','>=',min($value))` you're comparing value. whereIn for array value exists.

Comment: @DilipHirapara Thanks a lot! (gbalduzzi) pls update your answer

Comment: Ah, didn't see it was a whereIn statement. Updated